# Как можно обновить только несколько полей вложенной сущности?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Есть сущности «школьный класс» → «ученики» ↔️ «предметы». (связь один ко многим→, связь многие к многим ↔️).

Подскажите, можно ли как-то обновить часть полей для определенной сущность «предмет» более быстро и просто без перебора всех сущностей.
Вот как сейчас:

```cs
string studySubject_ = "Chemistry";
string newDescription = "learn about chemical";

AcademicSubject academicSubject = schoolClasses
    .Select(i => i.Pupils
        .Select(j => j.PupilAcademicSubjects
            .Where(i => i.AcademicSubject.Title.ToLower() == studySubject_.ToLower())
            .Select(k => k.AcademicSubject).FirstOrDefault()
        )
        .FirstOrDefault()
    )
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (academicSubject is not null)
{
   academicSubject.Description = newDescription;
   _appDBContext.AcademicSubjects.Update(academicSubject);
   _appDBContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

В LINQ происходит выборка предмет с названием "Химия" из коллекции "Школьный класс" с вложенностью описанной сверху.

Comment: Отформатируйте код, непонятно, что в linq происходит

Comment: Отформатировал и добавил описание для выборки